# How can I map json response into array angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

My response is getting mapped to undefined, I console log the response perfectly, but whenever I console log the array/json object they get set to undefined. Here is my code:

```
  public roles: any;


   private getGroups() {
     console.log("In Groups");
    let _url = "GroupsURL";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-User', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    headers.append('X-Token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    headers.append('X-AccessTime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(_url, options)
    .toPromise().then(response => {
      this.roles = response.json();
    })
  }
```

then in main I console log roles and it gets to be undefined

here is the constructor

```
 constructor() {
this.getGroups();
console.log(this.roles); <-- returns undefined
```

roles contains the same model as the json response containing the same data members such as:

```
    export class Group {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    pwd_expiry_in_days: string;
}
```

When I console log the response within the return, it logs the response perfectly, why is it out of scope from my main?

I can provide more details if needed. My main goal is to get from my server data and map it to my front end form to provide a list of roles to assign.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is async. But you work with code like it is sync. That will not work. Since that you need this:

```
  constructor() {
      this.getGroups()
        .then(roles => this.roles = roles); // <-- here you set internal roles property
      // ....
   }


   private getGroups() {
     console.log("In Groups");
    let _url = "GroupsURL";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-User', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    headers.append('X-Token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    headers.append('X-AccessTime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(_url, options)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
  }
```

*Note*: promises is not Angular (2+) way :) Observables now do this work.

Example with observables:

```
constructor() {
  this.getGroups()
    .subscribe(roles => this.roles = roles);
  }
}

private getGroups(): Observable<any> {
  // ....
  return this.http.get(_url, options)
    .map(response => response.json())
}
```

Don't worry about firing of fn you pass to subscribe more than 1 time. Http service always returns an observable which fires only 1 time.

Also check HttpClient service. It is new Angular API for Http calls. At least you don't need to call `json()` method on response each time =). More reading: https://angular.io/guide/http

Actually, Angular docs is perfect. A lot of useful things described there.

Chek out offictial docs for more examples and information: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#observables

Comment: I update my answer. Don't forget to return data in `then` fn in `getGroups` method.

Comment: alright, but how would I return data? isn't my function already returning the response?

Comment: Here is your function: http://i.imgur.com/uUiGp6B.png. It returns void. Check my function. My function returns response.

Comment: Oh, I'm very interested in doing it as an observable, any good examples so I can implement it using observables?

Comment: Thank you :), got it to work with Observables, however its still undefined in the component (anywhere outside the scope of the json response) how come simply mapping the response to my public object isn't working?

Comment: Do you use Http or HttpClient?

Comment: Try to debug this part of code: `.subscribe(roles => this.roles = roles);` Do you have roles there? If not put debugger here: `.map(response => response.json())`. Do you have correct response?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Http. My server sends me an array of the model I posted and I'm supposed to map it to my object so I can display it on the front end

Comment: Well it is not problem. Put some debuggers and track when you start to get wrong data. What is problem there?

Comment: yes for sure I'm getting a good response. However I have a public roles; when I set this.roles = response, roles is not getting the data from the response in the component. if I log roles, it returns undefined, if I log the response however, it returns the proper data members

Comment: What is `console.log(response.json())` in `getGroups`? Excatly. Do you have code as in my example?

Comment: Don't forget that you can not use json two times. So save result to the variable and return that variable. Also show me console.log of that variable.

Comment: "So save result to the variable and return that variable" is exactly what I'm trying to do but its not working, the variable is always undefined. public roles: any is my variable and I'm trying to assign the json response into it.

Comment: No. Wait. I am talking _now_ about that part of code: https://gist.github.com/sharikovvladislav/041da37b87c1f74976799c548065fcf2#file-lulz-L6. Please do same and send me what do you have in console?

Comment: moved discussion to -> https://gist.github.com/sharikovvladislav/041da37b87c1f74976799c548065fcf2#file-lulz-L6

Comment: @Dr.Geek Mine: http://prntscr.com/gehf0i. Yours: http://prntscr.com/gehfa3. Also your second `.then` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is async method and promise value is return also in a different time. When you call getGroups() method because of returning promise value. You need to get value in then () or have to use again then () to make sequential procedures like below;

```
private getGroups() {
     console.log("In Groups");
    let _url = "GroupsURL";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-User', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    headers.append('X-Token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    headers.append('X-AccessTime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(_url, options)
    .toPromise().then(response => {
      this.roles = response.json();
      console.log(this.roles);    // It will work

    })
    .then( data => {
     console.log(data);    // it also works
     }
  }
```

Comment: No, in the second `then`, `data` is undefined.

Comment: so whats the proper way to map it to my component from the method?

Comment: Because you need to return `this.roles` in first then.